# Process Builder Flow Criteria to include NULL Values

Tags: process-builder, flow

I'm new to flows and could use some help.  My flow was causing an error due to null values and by reading some of the exchanges, I was able to stop the errors.  However, now I'm expecting a use case to be updated and it's not.

My goal is that every time a user updates the related account on a case, also update the related account on the case's related contact record (with some exceptions).  Here is my formula:

```
AND(
[Case].ContactId <> "",
ISCHANGED([Case].AccountId),
[Case].Account.IsPersonAccount = False,
[Case].AccountId <> "001a000001XPA64AAH",
ISBLANK([Case].Contact.AccountId) = False && [Case].Contact.AccountId  <> "0013000000RdMKa",
OR(
ISBLANK([Case].Contact.AccountId) = True && ISBLANK([Case].Contact.Account.Name),
ISBLANK([Case].Contact.AccountId) = False && [Case].Contact.Account.Name = "Hold"  
)
)
```

It seems to be working in all scenarios except for this one:

```
ISBLANK([Case].Contact.AccountId) = True && ISBLANK([Case].Contact.Account.Name)
```

Basically, I would like it to update the account on the contact record if the contact is currently associated with the "Hold" account OR if the related account field is NULL.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: if `ISBLANK([Case].Contact.AccountId)` is true then by definition, the related Contact's `Account.Name` is null because the Contact is parentless

Comment: Thanks and agree.  I didn't have them both initially but in an attempt to get that to work I added it.  It doesn't work with or without.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
AND(
 ISCHANGED( [Case].Account ),
 /* can remove the below line if Account is a required field */
 NOT( ISBLANK( [Case].Account )),
 NOT( [Case].Account.IsPersonAccount ),
 [Case].AccountId <> "001a000001XPA64AAH",
 NOT( ISBLANK( [Case].Contact )),
 OR(
  ISBLANK( [Case].Contact.Account ),
  /* you might don't need this AccountId validation if Account Name is not 'Hold' */
  [Case].Contact.AccountId <> "0013000000RdMKa",
  [Case].Contact.Account.Name = "Hold"
 )
)
```

Comment: Your code will look nicer if you select it and hit `CTRL + K` instead of surrounding it with backticks (`\``).

Comment: Thanks, Adrian....my first paste on stack exchange...  I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.  It didn't recognize [Case].Contact.Account (without the ID or Name).  So far all of the hold account updates are working.  It's just the contacts that are blank that don't get updated at all. (At least they're not throwing null errors anymore - but still not working as expected)